# Sort the results of the first table by the id of the second

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I'm sorting some users by id (oldest to newest).

This is my accounts table:

`Accounts`

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | James |
| 2 | Kirk |
| 3 | Roberto |
| 4 | Lars |

However, I need to improve this ordering by relating a second messages table.

`Accounts_Messages`

| id | sender_id | receiver_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 4 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 1 | 3 |

In this case, users in Accounts table should be ordered by last messages.
**This is the expected result:**

Roberto;
Kirk;
Lars;

The question is: How can I sort the results of the first table by the id of the second?

I read that I need to use `JOIN` to relate these two tables, but I didn't know how to apply it in this specific case.

Thank you, guys!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey use this MySQL query for your aspected result

```
Select Accounts.name from Accounts_Messages left join Accounts on Accounts.id = Accounts_Messages.receiver_id order by Accounts_Messages.id DESC
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It's exactly what I expected! I made a small change to ensure unique results. This is the result:

`SELECT DISTINCT Accounts.name from Accounts_Messages left join Accounts on Accounts.id = Accounts_Messages.receiver_id order by Accounts_Messages.id DESC;`

But I found another problem now: it's working on localhost, but it doesn't work in production. Would you have any ideas?

Comment: means localhost and production I can't understand :)

Answer (score 0):

this is what I understand by your question you need to sort the accounts by the id of the accounts_Message

I think you should try

```
SELECT acc.* FROM Accounts_Message am LEFT OUTER JOIN Accounts acc USING(id) ORDER BY id ASC
```

if both Accounts and Accounts_Message has same column name id use  `USING(id)` or the column name is different use `ON acc.id = am.id` instead